# jQuery append and binding click event using on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-on, jquery-append

I am attempting to create a table row with a button in it that when clicked creates a new table row.  The new row also has the same "add line" button on it and I would like to be able to click that button to add another row.  But I cannot seem to get the click event to bind to an element that is appended within the click event.  I am sure I am using "on" incorrectly but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/vivojack/WkfvC/2/

my (simplified) html

```
<table id="ct">
    <tbody>
    <tr id="list_items_11" class="list_item">
        <td>This Line</td>
        <td><input type="button" name="addNewArea" class="addNewArea button" value="+"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

my (simplified) javascript

```
$('#ct tbody tr td').on('click', '.addNewArea', function(event) {   
    var areaCount = $('#ct tbody tr').length;
    var newAreaLine = '<tr id="list_items_' + areaCount + '" class="list_item"><td>New Line</td><td><input type="button" name="addNewArea" class="addNewArea button" value="+" /></td></tr>';
    $(newAreaLine).appendTo('#ct tbody');
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to bind the handler to an element that isn't dynamic. You're attempting to bind to the `td`, which doesn't exist when you do the binding. You can bind to the table instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/TMvN6/

```
$('#ct').on('click', '.addNewArea', function(event) {
```

Comment: So that's what I was doing wrong.  Totally missed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Z5Vvc/

You can try and simply attach it to the `$(document).on(` it now adds the "+" so on and so forth. Doc link is pretty saweet to read if you keen.

API doc: `.on` - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Hope this help your need `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).on('click', '.addNewArea', function(event) {    
    var areaCount = $('#ct tbody tr').length;
    var newAreaLine = '<tr id="list_items_' + areaCount + '" class="list_item"><td>New Line</td><td><input type="button" name="addNewArea" class="addNewArea button" value="+" /></td></tr>';
    $(newAreaLine).appendTo('#ct tbody');
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!  I upvoted your answer because it is right, but I accepted @JasonP's answer because it explained what I was doing wrong as well.