# Elements appeneded not triggering events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-append

I have a list

```
<ul id="list">
    <li> element one <span class="remover">X</span></li>
    <li> element two <span class="remover">X</span></li>
</ul>
```

and this list is dynamically appended with

```
<input type="text" id="adder">
<button id="add">Add</button>

<script>
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#list").append('<li>'+$("#adder").val()+' <span class="remover">X</span></li>');
    });
</script>
```

but the problem is this with part

```
<script> 
    $(".remover").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
</script>
```

The remove works perfectly with the *static added items*, but when it comes to the new appended items nothing happens on click, doesn't even trigger the function

Comment: Try event delegation... [Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery append and binding click event using on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282406/jquery-append-and-binding-click-event-using-on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#list').on('click', '.remover', function(e){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ddwCm/1/).

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: You can still use `this` in this case.

Comment: Of course...for some reason I always get caught out when switching from `addEventListener()` (where `this` is the element to which the eventListener was bound) and jQuery, where it's the element matching the selector (if a selector is used). Edited/corrected; thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
on('click',function(){})
```

not

```
.click()
```

refer to : http://api.jquery.com/on/

as click will relate to current item within document , while on is related to future items that will be added to document , however you should always use on with something that already exists in your document like for example the parent of the future added element so use something like

```
$("#parent").children("li").children('.remover').on("click",function(){bla bla bla;});
```

Comment: hey, thanks but click is working, but the removing part is not working on the newly added items.

Comment: You are right about using `on` but wrong about _how_ to use it. This will not solve the issue.

Comment: This selects the `#parent`, then binds the `on()`-bound functions to the existing-children of the `#parent`, *not* the dynamically-added children.

Comment: Oh no, no no. The edit is worse. Just look at [David Thomas' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20169293/7469).

Comment: this in my code refers to 2nd child of the parent !! which is remover class.

Comment: You are still _binding the handler only to the existing `remover` elements, not to the parent_.

Comment: in my answer the #parent refers to #list , it was a generic example !! there is no div with id="parent".

Comment: @Mathletics yes exactly so that he can use  $(this).parent().parent().remove();

Comment: _Sigh_. `$(this).parent().parent().remove()` would delete the __entire list__. In any case, the problem is not with the generic `parent` but rather __where__ you are binding the handler. Your example should be `$('#parent').on('click, '.remover', function() { ... })` in order to show event delegation. What you have will exhibit the same issue as OPs code.

Comment: '$("#parent").children("li").children('.remover').on("click",function(){bla bla bla;}) ' is same as '$('#parent').on('click, '.remover', function() { ... })' , anyway it is over no need to add more comments

Comment: @ProllyGeek you are absolutely, 100% wrong about those two code snippets being equivalent. The first option binds directly to the button at the time it is run; the second will listen for clicks on the parent which originate from the button. Go ahead and try it; you will see they are different.

Comment: ok i will consider trying it when i have time , thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Call the click function on list and set remover as target like so:

```
$( '#list' ).on( 'click', '.remover', function (e) {
    $(e.target).parent().remove();
});
```

You can't set a click event directly on it, it has to be set on the element that never is added to the page.

Comment: great explaination, thanks alot now it's clear to me